# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{(1-\cos(x-4))^4\ln^3(x-3)}{(e^{(x-4)^2}-1)^3\sin^5(3\pi x)}$

Tags: calculus

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{(1-\cos(x-4))^4\ln^3(x-3)}{(e^{(x-4)^2}-1)^3\sin^5(3\pi x)}$$

So we definitely use Taylor expansion

$\cos(x-4)=1-\frac{(x-4)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-4)^4}{4!}+\dots$

$\ln(x-3)=(x-4)-\frac{(4-x)^2}{2}-\frac{(4-x)^3}{3}-\frac{(4-x)^4}{4}+\dots$

$e^{(x-4)^2}=1+(x-4)^2+\frac{(x-4)^4}{2}+\frac{(x-4)^6}{6}+\dots$

$\sin(3\pi x)=3\pi x-\frac{(3\pi x)^3}{3!}+\frac{(3\pi x)^5}{5!}+\dots$

I know that $\lim_{x\to x}\frac{o(x^n)}{(x-a)^n}=0$, but how do I know until which term of the Taylor expansion I need?

Comment: @AakashKumar No! It is $\frac{1}{3888\pi^5}$

Comment: @JanEerland Yes you are correct

Comment: @gbox, Is the usage of Taylor's expansion mandatory?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee no

Comment: Is that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}$ instead of $\lim\limits_{x\to x}$ in the last line?

Comment: Dear gbox you can use substitution $x-4=t$and trig. identity$1-cost=2{sin^2}{t/2}$ then with L'hospital's rule we get the limit $\frac{2}{(6\pi)^5}$.

Answer (score 3):

As the usage of Taylor's expansion is not mandatory,

let $x-4=h,\sin(3\pi x)=\sin\{3\pi(4+h)\}=\sin(3\pi h)$

Now use $(i)\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{e^h-1}h=1$

$(ii)\lim_{u\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+u)}u=1$

$(iii)\lim_{v\to0}\dfrac{\sin v}v=1$

and $\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos y}{y^2}=\left(\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\sin y}y\right)^2\cdot\dfrac1{\lim_{y\to0}(1+\cos y)}=?$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{%
\lim_{x \to 4}{\bracks{1 -\cos\pars{x - 4}}^{\, 4}\,\ln^{3}\pars{x - 3} \over \bracks{\expo{\pars{x - 4}^{\,\, 2}} - 1}^{3}\sin^{5}\pars{3\pi x}}} =
\lim_{x \to 0}{\bracks{1 -\cos\pars{x}}^{\, 4}\,\ln^{3}\pars{x + 1} \over \bracks{\expo{x^{2}} - 1}^{3}\sin^{5}\pars{3\pi x}}
\\[3mm] = &\
16\lim_{x \to 0}{\sin^{8}\pars{x/2}\,\ln^{3}\pars{x + 1} \over \bracks{\expo{x^{2}} - 1}^{3}\sin^{5}\pars{3\pi x}}
\\[3mm] = &\
{1 \over 3888\pi^{5}}\,\lim_{x \to 0}\bracks{\sin\pars{x/2} \over x/2}^{8}\bracks{3\pi x \over \sin\pars{3\pi x}}^{5}
\bracks{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x}^{3}\bracks{x^{2} \over \expo{x^{2}} - 1}^{3}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

In expression $\ds{\pars{1}}$, all the "$\ds{\bracks{\cdots}}$-expressions" $\ds{\to 1}$ when $\ds{x \to 0}$. Then,
$$
\color{#f00}{%
\lim_{x \to 4}{\bracks{1 -\cos\pars{x - 4}}^{\, 4}\,\ln^{3}\pars{x - 3} \over \bracks{\expo{\pars{x - 4}^{\,\, 2}} - 1}^{3}\sin^{5}\pars{3\pi x}}} =
\color{#f00}{1 \over 3888\pi^{5}} \approx 8.4047 \times 10^{-7}
$$